# React Native Swiping vertical ScrollViews to the left and right

Tags: reactjs, react-native, swipe

I am building a book application in which I use the `ScrollView` component to render a chapter, so that I can be able to scroll up and down when reading the chapter.

I want to add the ability to swipe left and right between the chapters. How can I implement that? I have checked the documentation but couldn't find a way to implement it.

Comment: Should you add your code snippet on your question. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Set **horizontal** props to true in ScrollView Component

When true, the scroll view's children are arranged horizontally in a row instead of vertically in a column. The default value is false.

```
<ScrollView 
  contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
  horizontal={true}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: yeah, I know how to do that, but I also want each of the children to have a vertical scroll. that means I want to flip between children, and each of the child views should be scrollable horizontally. Do you know how I can do that? @John

Comment: I want the same @AwaDesmoline, Can you please let me know how did you do that.

Comment: @ManishShrivastava you can use https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper to do it with